# How to pull data from S3 using Spark

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have a bunch of csv files containing time and space dependent dats in an AWS S3 bucket. The files are prefixed with timestamps on 5mins granularity.
When trying to access them from AWS EMR with Apache Spark and trying to filter them both time and space even beefy clusters (5 x r3.8xlarge) are crashing. The data for I'm trying to do the filtering with broadcast join.
Location is a class with a userid, timestamp and a mobile cell information which I'm trying to join with the cell position information (segmentDF) to filter only those records that are required.

I need further processing of these records, here just try to save them as parquet. I feel there must be a more efficient way of doing it, starting from storing the data in an S3 bucket. Any ideas are appreciated.

http://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219 suggests an alternative and faster way of accessing S3 buckets from spark which I could not implement (see below for code and error rep).

```
    \\ Scala code for the filtering 
    val locationDF = sc.textFile(s"bucket/location_files/201703*")
        .map(line => {
            val l = new Location(line)
            (l.id, l.time, l.cell)
        })
        .toDF("id", "time", "cell")

    val df = locationDF.join(broadcast(segmentDF), Seq("cell"), "inner").select($"id", $"time", $"lat", $"lng", $"cellName").repartition(32)

    df.write.save("somewhere/201703.parquet")



\\ Alternative way of accessing S3 keys
import com.amazonaws.services.s3._, model._
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials

import com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

val credentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials

val request = new ListObjectsRequest()

request.setBucketName("s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket")
request.setPrefix("location_files")
request.setMaxKeys(32000)
def s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId, credentials.getAWSSecretKey))

val objs = s3.listObjects(request) 
sc.parallelize(objs.getObjectSummaries.map(_.getKey).toList)
        .flatMap { key => Source.fromInputStream(s3.getObject(bucket, key).getObjectContent: InputStream).getLines }
```

Latter ends up with error `com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: PermanentRedirect; Request ID: DAE08BA90C01EB5E)`

Comment: are your EMR cluster and S3 bucket in the same data centre?

Comment: Yes, they are both in eu-west-1.

Comment: Have you tried to add `s3.setEndpoint("eu-west-1")` before the call to `listObjects` (and in your bucket name remove `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`)?